# If$f \in L_1 (R)$ so that $xf(x), x \hat{f}(x) \in L_1 (\mathbb R)$, show that $\sum|\hat{f}(n)| \le \infty$ and finally Poisson summation formula

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

> **PROBLEM** (1)$f \in L_1 (\mathbb R)$ so that $xf(x), x \hat{f}(x) \in L_1 (\mathbb R)$, show that $\sum|\hat{f}(n)| \le \infty$.
>
> (2)Also, show that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} f(x-2\pi n)$ converges
>   uniformly on $[-\pi, \pi]$
>
> (3)Finally, prove the *Poisson summation formula*: for every $x \in
> > \mathbb R$ 
>   $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+2 \pi n) = 1/2 \pi
> > \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat f (n)e^{inx} $$

I even obstruct by (1) and cannot continue.
Using the condition, Fourier inversion and dominated convergence , $xf(x), x \hat{f}(x) \in L_1 (\mathbb R)$, I can show successively $\hat{f} \in L_1 (\mathbb R)$ , $f \in C_0 (\mathbb R)$ and $f \in C_0^1 (\mathbb R)$
Symmetrically, I also can show  $\hat f \in C_0^1 (\mathbb R)$.

Provided $f' \in L_1 (\mathbb R)$, we will have:
$$
 \hat f (n) =\int_{\mathbb R}\,f(x)e^{-i n x} dx 
= \frac{f(x)e^{-i n x}}{-inx} \Big |^{\infty}_{-\infty}+(in)^{-1}\int_{\mathbb R}\,f'(x)e^{-i n x} dx 
=(in)^{-1} \widehat{f'}(n)
$$
I try to imitate the proof of the corresponding question regarding $L_1 (\mathbb T)$, however, it doesn't work since we don't have  $f' \in L_1 (\mathbb R)$.
Please help!

Comment: I'm starting to doubt that this problem is correct. Those regularity conditions do not seem to be sufficient to force absolute convergence of the series in 1. Even if $f'\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, we would have have that $\hat f(n)$ decays like $1/n$, as you note, which does not suffice. Observe that Folland in his book and Stein and Weiss in their book both impose a sharper decay condition in the hypotheses of the theorem.